How to check if graphql-dgs-spring-graphql version is compatible with spring-graphql version?
I'm having a problem when I run a gradle command for my git repo (./gradlew clean test)... I think my issue is due to a version mismatch between the graphql-dgs-spring-graphql and spring-graphql libraries, but I don't know how to check if the versions used are compatible.
My terminal shows graphql-dgs-spring-graphql is version 9.1.3 and spring-graphql is version 1.2.5. My question is: are these versions compatible? Do I have to downgrade one or upgrade the other?
Thank you!

***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist.

    The following method did not exist:

        'org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap org.springframework.graphql.execution.SchemaReport.unmappedArguments()'

    The calling method's class, com.netflix.graphql.dgs.springgraphql.autoconfig.DgsSpringGraphQLSourceAutoConfiguration, was loaded from the following location:

And also:
Action:

    Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.netflix.graphql.dgs.springgraphql.autoconfig.DgsSpringGraphQLSourceAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.graphql.execution.SchemaReport

I tried upgrading spring-graphql in my build.gradle dependencies file like this:
implementation 'org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql:1.3.0' 
which did not work. I've tried running this with 1.3.0, 1.3.3, and also 1.2.9, with the same failed result.
